# use lapply function to modify several matrices in R

Tags: r, list, function, matrix, lapply

I'd like to delete one column (f.e. column 3) from several matrices that are stored in a list.

Can I do this without defining a function?

This is the approach using an own function:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
m2 <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
m3 <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
m_ls <- list(m1,m2,m3)

del <- function(mat){
  mat <- mat[,-3]
  return(mat)
}

lapply(m_ls, del)
```

Comment: You can also just use an anonymous function, something like: `lapply(m_ls, \(x) x[,-3])`

Comment: This is also nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `[` as a function:

```r
m1 <- m2 <- m3 <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
m_ls <- list(m1,m2,m3)

lapply(m_ls, `[`, , -3)
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    4
#> [2,]    2    5
#> [3,]    3    6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    4
#> [2,]    2    5
#> [3,]    3    6
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    4
#> [2,]    2    5
#> [3,]    3    6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>